# How to disable a keyboard input after maxlength exceeds?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

">

```
<ion-content>

    <h3 class="style3"><strong>Message</strong></h3>

       <form name="form1"> 

          <div class="list">

             <label class="item item-input"  >

                <input type="text"  placeholder="Enter Number"ng-blur='SendInvit()' ng-model="message.name" name="phone" ng-required="true" />

            <span class="error-message" ng-show="form1.phone.$dirty&&form1.phone.$invalid"> </span>

       </label>
```

```
<input type="text" rows="4" cols="" placeholder="Write Your Message" 

   class="area" name="phone" ng-model="message.description" ng-maxlength=
```

"{{maxLength}}" ng-change="updateBody();" ng-required="true">

```
<span class="error-message" ng-show="form1.phone.$dirty &&form1.phone.$invalid"></span>

<div id="characters">

    <span>Characters left: {{maxLength - message.description.length}}</span>
```

Send



  




  Cancel

Below is the plunker of my work.Please help me with the code
http://plnkr.co/edit/NDGeMcqzpbIqwd8sr5jM

Answer (score 0):

Used `ng-disabled` when the form is invalid with `ng-maxlength`. Set the maxlength from your controller.

Max-length:

```
ng-maxlength="maxlength"
```

Ng-disabled

```
 ng-disabled="form1.phone.$invalid"
```

Here is a working example.

https://plnkr.co/edit/FC4vXw1311pnMee8d2Lz?p=preview

if you want simple solution use  `maxlength="10"`!

Good luck.

Comment: But could you please explain why binding and ng-change didn't work?I really want to know